# When is it reasonable to create my own programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, dsl

Are there types of killer applications, classes of algorithmic problems, etc., where it is better, in the long run, to create my own language?

PS: Just to be sure, I mean a new programming language and a compiler, not a new compiler for an existing language.

**EDIT**: Thank you for the answers. Can you provide some examples, where it is absolutly unnecessary to create a DSL or cases in which a DSL might be a good idea?

Comment: I believe that one should create a DSL for *every* problem.

Comment: Isn't this what LISP is great for?

Comment: @Darknight, not necessarily Lisp - any language with decent metaprogramming cababilities is ok.

Comment: When you have a desire to learn about compiler internals.

Comment: When you think it would be fun or educational.  Designing a new language that needs its own compiler never serves any useful purpose, given the amount of effort involved.  (There are, of course, people who are sufficiently intelligent, educated, and experience to know when to ignore my advice.)

Comment: The border between a command queue design pattern and a programming language is a blurry one, and there are many situations where command queue is quite desired... and as it grows, it may turn into a very simple, interpreted scripting language embedded in your application.

Comment: its only worthwhile if you're also going to build a debugger, a profiler and associated tools ;) got time for that? no didn't think so :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It certainly is relevant for a person to write their own language for educational purposes. To learn about programming language design and about compiler design.  But real-world uses are few and far between.

In writing your own language you are:

- Adding a tremendous amount of complexity to your problem
- Adding a significant amount of work in writing and maintaining the new language and compiler

So, if you plan to write your own language for your project then the features that it provides that other languages don't have need to offset the above costs.

Take games development for example.  They often need mini-languages within their games or scripting languages.  They use these languages to script out a huge amount of the in-game events that happen.  However, even in this case, they almost always choose existing scripting languages and tailor them to their needs.

Comment: E.g., WoW uses XML & Lua for its scripting needs.

Comment: I do have to mention that in "The Pragmatic Programmer" that writing smaller, domain-specific languages to aid in a task is incredibly helpful and encouraged.  I wouldn't recommend writing a full-fledged general purpose language, but a metalanguage that generates code can be helpful at times.

Comment: It is a lie. Writing a language *does not* add a complexity - normally it will reduce the complexity significantly. Implementing a compiler and maintaining it is a tiny piece of work anyway.

Comment: @SK-logic, "Implementing a compiler and maintaining it is a tiny piece of work anyway".  Have you tried?  For what processor?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I am doing it for living. Nowdays you don't have to target any given CPU directly - since there are great VMs available, like LLVM, .NET, even JVM. And if you're not going to do too much of the expensive optimisations, even targeting a "real" CPU is not a big deal - see the OCaml compiler for an example of this primitivistic approach.

Comment: @SK-logic, so you compile to byte-codes for a virtual machine, not actual cpu instructions.   Having a highly optimizing virtual machine can allow you to generate unoptimized code.  I am not certain though, that I would consider that a full compiler, since you essentially skip the assembler and linking step.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, by definition compiler is translating from one language to another. The level of that target language does not matter anything. And no one sane will implement a full optimising compiler back-end for a DSL - it is better to reuse the existing one. Actually, most modern DSLs are compiled into C. As for assembler and linker - they've been always considered separate from compilation, since the very early days of the system programming.

Answer (score 26):

Let me just quote Paul Vick, ex chief developer of the VB compiler and now working on Project Oslo and the M language:

> It’s mind-bendingly, stupendously difficult to build a new language, even one that’s largely based on an existing one. Yet many programmers think, “hey, *I* use languages, how hard can this be?” and go at it. … probably over 98% of them fail to ever gain any traction at all, but god bless the optimists because without them we’d never get the 2% of languages that succeed. I’m personally willing to sacrifice the millions of dollars and hours wasted on languages that never make it just so that we can get languages like C# and Java and Ruby and Python and so on.
>
> So the fact that coming up with a new language is a bad idea shouldn’t dissuade people from developing new DSLs, it should just give them pause and hopefully a little humility. The key, I think, is to start small and to stay small.

[DSLs: Definitely a bad idea!](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2009/01/26/dsls-definitely-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: Isn't VBA a DSL in some ways?

Comment: yep, and it's a bad idea!  (well, seriously, a DSL is for one application. VBA, OTOH, tries to turn applications into platforms)

Comment: VBA: Definitely a bad idea! How can we trust someone who was in charge of developing VB? :-D Good article though

Comment: VB != VBA. By the way, is it even legal to criticize VBA on this site? After all, Joel helped develop it, right?

Comment: I was mostly joking. But I am not a fan of VBA, its clunky and messy IMHO. (Also, I know VB != VBA) I'm sure Joel can handle criticism..

Comment: although pragmatic programmer was such a good book, recommendation of DSLs in that book was plain stupid. In the same way that they recommended learning a new language every year, IMHO that's pretty stupid as well.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph The link doesn't work. The [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rPc64BwQ_AcJ:www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2009/01/26/24808.aspx+%22DSLs:+Definitely+a+bad+idea!%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com) does.

Comment: There's a reason why link dumping is considered a bad answer, and it's because the link is now quite out of date.

Comment: @DeadMG Annoying, I know. There’s the archive.org link however.

Comment: DSLs are fine.  You just want them to be a subset of an existing language, so you can use that compiler.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Those would be EDSLs, popular in Ruby (but also in C++, see Boost.Spirit). But Paul Vick’s point was explicitly about non-embedded DSLs.

Comment: I just edited your answer to point to [Paul Vick's article](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2009/01/26/dsls-definitely-a-bad-idea/) again rather than the Google cache. In 2011 he "reset his blog" and deleted all the VB content, but in 2012 he put it back although with different URLs. Sounds like [he was personally having a hard time](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2012/10/02/undoing-some-of-the-damage/) when he deleted that stuff.

Comment: @MarkJ Thanks a lot. And, wow, that article does *not* make for pleasant reading. Hope he’s doing better now.

Comment: Thanks for the kind comments, I'm actually now [working on JavaScript](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2012/02/22/i-used-to-be-a-blogger-like-you/) and, yes, things are quite a bit better. :-)

Not sure why the original link didn't work, I tried to get all the old link styles working, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 22):

When is it reasonable?

**When you feel like it!**

Don't listen to these people who have snarky comments that basically say:

"Don't do it because its too hard and X language is better than any language you can come up with".

The thing is, creating a DSL happens all the time. A framework is a DSL. A macro is a DSL. Every time you write a function for your program, that is part of a DSL. Sure, its within the bounds of the grammar, but vocabulary is part of a language. This is why industries often create their own vernacular: its more efficient!

If "don't do it" was the right answer, we would all be writing COBOL and Fortran.

Comment: Really? I would consider frameworks, macros and functions all to be things that help a language maintain domain independence.

Comment: @CurtainDog, it only becomes part of the language if its part of the standard library. Otherwise it is a "dialect" of the language.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to read parts of [Martin Fowler's upcoming DSL book](http://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html), if you're thinking of writing you own language.

I can't really think of a business case to create a language from scratch other than it being a tremendous learning experience.

Edit: for DSL's there are plenty of business cases, but the key here is not to get carried away and Keep It Simple.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that the key questions are, "What problem am I trying to solve?" and "Who gets the ROI?"

If you're trying to build your own skills and experience, then full speed ahead, but not in a production system that's supposed to solve someone else's problem.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like the main reason you'd want a new language is that you start discovering patterns in your code that existing languages don't handle well.  But there are a bunch of problems with creating your own language.  You'll be missing out on all the libraries and frameworks that are built up for existing languages.  You'll spend a lot of time designing and implementing the new language, which is all time you don't have to spend on the real programming task.  You'll spend a lot of effort convincing other developers that they should use your language.  And, you'll have a hard time recruiting and training new developers.

Why not write in a language like Lisp that lets you extend the language as you discover new patterns?  Then, you get all the power of a new language with all the benefits of an established language.

Answer (score 6):

One reason could be to create it as an experiment to learn about language design and compiler building.

Another reason could be to build a scripting language into an application when you don't have the option to add a third-party API.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can program **without** creating a new language, so it's good to realize that's what you're doing and understand the issues.

- What is a language?
  Vocabulary, syntax, and semantics.

An off-the-shelf language like VB, Java, C#, etc. is just a **base** language. As soon as you add classes, methods, etc. to it, you have added vocabulary and semantics.
There are many ways to implement languages - parsing & translating, parsing & interpreting, macros on top of an existing language, adding classes&methods to an existing language.

- What do you want a language to do?
  Be good for expressing problems concisely.

How do you know if you've done this? The measure I use is **edit count**. If one-sentence requirement A comes along, I proceed to implement the requirement in code. When I'm done & got all the bugs out, I check in the code, and the code repository gives me a list of the changes I made, B. **The smaller B is, the better the language is.** Averaged over the space of real & possible requirements, that measure tells me how "domain specific" the language is.

- Why is conciseness good?
  Because it minimizes bugs.

If it takes N code changes to implement 1 requirement, and you sometimes make mistakes, then the number of bugs you introduce is roughly proportional to N. In the limit where N = 1, it is **almost impossible to introduce a bug** without trying to.

Note that this is a direct challenge to the "code bloat" we see nowadays.

**ADDED:** In response to your request for an example, see [differential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371898/how-does-differential-execution-work). I won't say it can be understood quickly, but it does significantly reduce UI code.

Comment: If one-sentence requirements existed we'd all be coding in English. Just like any human language, code requires a whole lot of boilerplate in order to have any meaning.

Comment: @Dog: From an AI viewpoint, that would be ideal. Take a look at differential execution. That's a real example of cutting the source code by an order of magnitude. Boilerplate may be necessary, but it's not a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

It is always "feasible", to use the word in your (original) question, but it is not very often useful and very rarely optimal given the abundance of well-supported and mature languages and frameworks that exist.

It is an interesting intellectual challenge, however.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. Non-native speaker... :)

Comment: oh, didn't know that and your post is in excellent English, so hard to tell.  Not trying to be grammar police either - apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Only if your team's core business is programming languages.

I've worked on a programming language that was created in a financial company.

Clearly, for the architect himself this was a great challenge and improved his own skills.

Inevitably, the language couldn't grow or improve at anywhere near the rate that something like C# or Java could - they have teams dedicated to doing that.

The language soon stagnated as no one new wanted to take on the task of improving someone else's pet project.

The original architect left. The language withered and died after 10 years.

Those 10 years were hell for anyone who had the misfortune to work on a dead-end language.

So go ahead, create your own language but please don't ask anyone else to actually use it. Please don't expect anyone else to thank you for it.

Comment: Interesting case study... could such stagnation be averted by targetting a language for say the Java or .NET platforms. That way the language can 'grow' as more is added to the base libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd create a language that targeted another one like Java. Why not just use Java or C# to start with?

Answer (score 4):

Designing languages can be fun. But you don't have to ristrict yourself to programming languages.

If I build a moderately complex application, I like to add a kind of macro/scripting language to make it easier to execute complex repetitive tasks. Most users won't use this functionality, but the few that do use it are very grateful. Besides, i make sure it is valuable for the support people to help them fixing customer problems.

Answer (score 4):

It's completely reasonable if done to extend your skills and to learn.

Other than that, if you have to ask the question, then it's not.  If you're trying to figure out whether you can deal with a certain class of algorithm or a certain problem domain better than existing languages, first off you need to be an expert in the area you are addressing.  You will know it is appropriate when your skills and experience tell you so.

And you could be wrong about that, too, but you'd need another expert to convince you of that (or to show you that you aren't the expert you think you are).  A lively discussion that would be, not a simple Q-and-A as you'll find here.

Answer (score 4):

Except for self-educational purposes, I would like to claim that there is today **no need whatsoever** to create your own language. In any circumstance. Ever. Regardless of what you want to do, there are boatloads of existing languages you can take/adapt to your needs.

Comment: Your claim is extremely controversial, and sounds like a rant to me.

Comment: Today there are several frameworks for creating your own customised DSLs, which I don't really cover what I was trying to say (this was 2 years ago). I should probably reformulate it as "implementing a new general-purpose language from scratch is in practise never the right way to go." :)

Comment: ok, this "general purpose" addition changes everything. But, I do not believe in "general purpose" languages - none of them is really general enough, so still there is a plenty of space for new "somewhat general" languages (which are all, in fact, DSLs of a sort).

Answer (score 3):

It definitively depends on the situation. As nosklo said - If you have a good idea, a brand new concept or something like that I would highly recommend you to do that.

In general I would suggest to rely upon established technology.

But if you're interested in creating your own "language" you should check out: YACC & Lex

Answer (score 3):

You can, just don't catch yourself in the anti-pattern "Recreating the square wheel".

Meaning you are recreating whats already been done, only poorer than the original(s).

Comment: If wheels weren't recreated we could've been still using rock wheels. Rock it baby

Answer (score 3):

Wouter was known for creating a new language for any new idea. 
You can draw inspiration from his work: [Wouter's programming language page](http://strlen.com/proglang/index.html).

Comment: that's very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

When to create your own language?

When you want to, as a large hobby project.

For a domain-specific language.  These can be quite elaborate; look at what goes on in the Interactive Fiction (or text adventure) community by checking out [the archive](http://ifarchive.org).

When your aims are very ambitious, and you think you can make a real advance, like Paul Graham's [Arc project](http://www.paulgraham.com/arc.html).

Also, in any sufficiently adaptable language (perhaps C++, definitely Common Lisp) in the process of developing low-level constructs.

When to avoid it like you would, I hope, avoid a cliche like avoiding it like the plague?

When it's to be the basis of continuing development for real projects.  It will always wind up lagging seriously behind what's commercially available for cheap, and will cripple further development.  I worked for a company with its own version of COBOL, and never want to work at another company that maintains its own language.  We watched other versions of COBOL get better capabilities, and better tools, while we were stuck with the same problems.  (I don't want to work with COBOL ever again, but that's another story.)

The situations in which you might create your own language don't fall into this.  Hobby projects are not used for real development.  Something like Arc will succeed (and get multiple implementations and further evolution and development) or fail (and nobody else will use it).  A small domain-specific language is only part of a project, and since it's small it can be improved over time.  A text adventure language is used to write individual games, and those games, in addition to being hobby projects, are almost never used for continuing development.

Answer (score 3):

My perspective is that DSLs are generally a "weak idea", and it's more productive in the long run to use a standard language and build your domain-specific needs as a library of the "non-DSL".

However, it may turn out to be that your needs are custom enough that it's preferable to have a DSL(not just a slightly modified gcc or lisp implementation) for your company. Many companies use drop-ins of current languages that target what they are doing, without writing/maintaining their own language. E.g., I've heard that PHP has a nice drop-in; Lua is designed around being a drop-in, ModelView uses Python and AutoCAD has AutoLISP as its scripter.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with writing your own programming language if you can leverage existing tools.  In todays world this would mean that you either define it in a syntax usable to an existing language (like Java or C#) or write a small transformation system (macro expander) that generate code in an existing language.

Going all the way to machine code is reinventing a LOT of wheels...

A very good reason for a DSL is to represent domain data in a succinct way.  This allows domain experts to work with the data directly instead of having to go through others.  The trick is then to have the resulting programs in an easy to process form.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking the answer would be a big NO. Of the hundreds of languages out there there is usually one that will suit your problem.

However there are circumstance where it is a rational option to develop a new language:-

- When one of your competitors now owns one of your main development platforms. I am thinking of Googles current reliance on Java and their development of "go", (it helps if you have an author of the most successful language ever on the payroll!).
- When you have to write a ton of code for a new platform and the existing languages are verbose and error prone -- e.g. php for web development.
- When you come across problems of scale and parallelism which were never encountered before because nobody ever had this much hardware to process this much data before -- e.g. Scala and (to a certain extent GO).

Answer (score 2):

What language is good at is *compositionality* or putting the same components together in different ways.

If your domain problem just needs you to set a bunch of orthogonal switches, a language probably doesn't add much over forms, a graphic UI or a straight text-config. file. (I'm assuming here that a file full of key, value pairs *isn't* what you mean by a "language".)

OTOH, if your configuration is like real language eg. verbs and nouns can be put together in many different (and novel) combinations to any degree of complexity, then a language is going to become almost inevitable, because the combinatorial explosion of trying to specify what you want by any other method overwhelms.

Answer (score 1):

Learning exercises aside, it is reasonable to create your own programming language only when you understand other languages, your specific problem domain, and the way that existing languages address that problem domain and this understanding is thorough enough that you **know** a new language is a reasonable solution without needing to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I set out to do that on a hobby project I started specifying what I wanted the syntax to look like and realized partway through I was reinventing prolog.  Other languages that might be a good fit when you think you need to invent a language are lisp, lua, or something like Haskell.  Basically, all those languages you ignored in college because you thought they would never be useful.

Comment: I routinely use more than a dozen of very different languages. Including Prolog, various Lisps and Haskell. But still I tend to solve almost any problem by implementing a DSL for it. And that DSLs are specific enough to be far from any of the existing languages - they look more like a mixture of tiny parts of the different languages.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is for educational purposes, as already stated. But there are more. For example, there are many research languages like `Sing#` on the [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=69431) operating system  and `BitC` on [Coyotos](http://www.coyotos.org/docs/osverify-2004/osverify-2004.html) that have been designed because the existing languages don't offer the required features (for instance verification on a language level).

Answer (score 1):

Tom Van Cutsem recently wrote an essay answer to this very question:

http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/whypls.html

Bullet summary (from that page):

- Language as syntactic abstraction mechanism: to reduce repetitive "boilerplate" code that cannot be abstracted from using another language's built-in abstraction mechanisms.

  Language as thought shaper: to induce a paradigm shift in how one should structure software (changing the "path of least resistance").

  Language as a simplifier: to boil down an existing paradigm to just its essential parts, often to increase understanding and insight.

  Language as law enforcer: to enforce important properties or invariants, possibly to make it easier to infer more useful properties from programs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably never.

Lua is the best choice you can get if you want to embed the language in basically any other language.

Small Domain Specifc Languages are currently in, and it make sense in some applications.

Other then that, reasons are mainly academical.

Creating a language when its not needed, is really a bad thing to do due to the complexity involved in developing and maintaing it. I have seen many projects that introduce some kind of scripting language specific only to that program, and it was the thing that was slowing down development of the base thing by huge amount. Good examples are for instance automation languages like Phantom, AutoHotKey, AutoIt. Those tools would be IMO much better if they used some well known emeding langauge like Lua.

Comment: Lua is slo-o-o-o-w. But, on the other hand, there is a MetaLua with some decent metaprogramming capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'edit' seems to be a substantially different question ("when should I build a DSL?" rather than the original question which people understood as "when should I build a new, general purpose programming language").  It seems people have thoroughly answered the 'original' question but there are few answers giving specific criteria for when to use a DSL.  So I propose a checklist :

1. Your userbase is larger than a few people, generally non-technical and / or with restricted system access (hence it's unreasonable to expect them to learn / use an existing general purpose language).  If it is within your dev team or software organisation you could instead say "just write a script".
2. Your users need to use it sufficiently often, with sufficiently varied and changing behaviours needed (i.e. you can't just provide a fixed library of functions maintained by you)
3. The behaviour that users can specify is too complicated to specify as data (e.g. you can't achieve it using a database table, or a user-input matrix, or a list of tasks, or a key-value collection...think carefully because you can achieve a lot of complexity with these).  If you can achieve the behaviour using data input or configuration instead of DSL then you probably should because it will be much less work.  Some kind of conditionality, or composability / chaining together, or modelling a few different abstractions may be signs that the behaviour you need is too complex for plain data / configuration
4. But the behaviour is still restricted enough that you can specify it in a concise DSL.  A big danger is 'platform bloat' e.g. if users start to request "can you just add...?".  If they need to connect to the internet, or read and write from the file system, or open and close processes - then this is no longer a DSL. (I have seen this happen for real...users allowed to embed small python calls, gradually growing to python scripts, and eventually destroying any limits / modularity / performance)

If all of these are true then a DSL may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there types of killer applications, classes of algorithmic
>   problems, etc., where it is better, in the long run, to create my own
>   language?

It depends.

Let's take our brain. It seems to be such a complex mess that we encounter borders with ANY programming language (at least now). So maybe in order to actually virtualize our brain we need other approaches and therefor other semantics and syntaxes.

Generally speaking, there are yet such complex topics which might lead to other strategies which would also include a 'better' language for a given scenario.